# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto ASP.NET FrameWork 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo un error que me arroja la Excepcion de System.NullReferenceException o Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Agrego un punto de interferencia en la llave de la conexion hacia la base de datos pero a la hora de llegar al primer parametro (@identificacion) salta hacia la excepcion.

Quisiera saber cual es el error

y Este este es bloque de codigo donde arrajo ese error:

`public bool GuardarPaciente(PacienteDto pacienteDto)
        {

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionSQL"].ConnectionString))
            {

                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_paciente", connect);

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@procedure", 1);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identificacion", pacienteDto.Identificacion);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_completo", pacienteDto.Nombre_completo);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", pacienteDto.Direccion);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", pacienteDto.Telefono);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horario_contacto", pacienteDto.Horario_contacto);

                connect.Open(); //abre la conexion hacia la base de datos

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message_err = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`

Comment: Puedes añadir un pantallazo de la excepción?. Prueba esto: `pacienteDto?.Identificacion`, si no te da error es que `pacienteDto` está llegando a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tu instancia a pacienteDto tenga valores nulos, puedes condicionar relizar las operaciones solo si pacienteDto tiene valores diferentes a null

ejemplo:

```
 try
            {
    if(pacienteDto!=null){
                using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionSQL"].ConnectionString))
                {

                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_paciente", connect);

                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@procedure", 1);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identificacion", pacienteDto.Identificacion);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_completo", pacienteDto.Nombre_completo);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", pacienteDto.Direccion);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", pacienteDto.Telefono);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horario_contacto", pacienteDto.Horario_contacto);

                    connect.Open(); //abre la conexion hacia la base de datos

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true
                }
}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message_err = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
```